# Is it possible to set specific border side color of GridItem in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, border, flex-mx

What I would like to achieve is for GridItem , I would like to set left/right/top/bottom border side with specific color.

For instance,like the css:

```
border-left:solid red 3px;
border-right:solid violet 4px;
border-top:solid blue 4px;
border-bottom:solid green 4px;
```

How to set a specific border side color with a specific color(different border side color) in ActionScript? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use style to draw border for GridItem, like this :

```
GridItem.setStyle("borderColor","red");
GridItem.setStyle("borderSides","left top right bottom");
GridItem.setStyle("borderStyle","inset");
GridItem.setStyle("borderThickness",4);
```